# How to startActivity with a ShareCompat.IntentBuilder

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appcompat

I'm attempting to add a shared intent to post to *Google Plus* and can't seem to resolve the issue of passing the new `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder` (Android support library class) to the `startActivity` method. I'm started out using [this example](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2012/05/sharing-rich-content-from-your-android.html). My app is compiled using Android 2.2 platform. Is it possible that there is another supporting way to start the Activity to launch the shared intent.

```
IntentBuilder shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(MyActivity.this);                
shareIntent.setText(message);
shareIntent.setSubject(subject);

if (mFullFileName != null) {
    File imageFile = new File(mFullFileName);
    if (imageFile.exists()) {
        shareIntent.setStream(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    }
} else {
    shareIntent.setType("*.*");
}   
shareIntent.getIntent();
// doesn't compile only accepts Intent and not the Intentbuilder 
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: wat is the error you are getting? Put logcat output if possible.

Comment: Sorry.. my post wasn't as accurate as I first thought.. I added a comment block to the startActivity method.. its a compile issue, can't seem to get to work for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thats an example from my code, but if you want some reference material tap on the hyperlink for an article.

```
public void shareText(String text) {
        String mimeType = "text/plain";
        String title = "Example title";

        Intent shareIntent =   ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                                                    .setType(mimeType)
                                                    .setText(text)
                                                    .getIntent();
        if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
            startActivity(shareIntent);
        }
    }
```

[Blog post on ShareCompat.IntentBuilder and sharing intents](https://medium.com/google-developers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b)

Comment: Just FYI, you can substitute `getIntent` for `createChooserIntent` to force a chooser. This way, you don't  have to check if the package manager will be able to resolve the activity as the chooser will handle that.

Comment: where did u use title?

Answer (score 16):

`ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(ActivityName.this)` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ShareCompat.IntentBuilder#from(android.app.Activity)), use the constructor of IntentBuilder like this:

**Kotlin:**

```
    ShareCompat
               .IntentBuilder(this@YourActivity)
               .setType("text/plain")
               .setChooserTitle("Share text with: ")
               .setText("Desired text to share")
               .startChooser()
```

**Java:**

```
new ShareCompat
                .IntentBuilder(YourActivity.this)
                .setType("text/plain")
                .setChooserTitle("Share text with: ")
                .setText("Desired text to share")
                .startChooser();
```

Answer (score 9):

Funny, I just figured it out... the example given was suppose create an Intent and not an IntentBuilder object..   had to change my code to chain the object creation.

```
Intent i = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(MyActivity.this)
                       .setText(message)
                       .setSubject(subject)
                       .setStream(Uri.fromFile(imageFile))
                       .setType("image/jpeg")
                       .getIntent()
                       .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
```

Comment: Be aware, Uri.fromFile(imageFile) is not safe since Nougat. "Passing file:// URIs outside the package domain may leave the receiver with an unaccessible path." https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#perm